# Parsing an RSS feed with jfeed fails only for some fields

Tags: jquery, rss, jfeed

I'm using the latest version of jFeed with the latest jQuery. I know jFeed is rather outdated, and no longer supported, but firefox seems to be the only browser that is having an issue parsing an RSS feed using this setup. I've modified jFeed to pull a 'date' field which is in the XML node "dc:date". The only thing I can think of is firefox is having an issue because of the semicolon. (All other fields are working fine and do not have this character in them).

I've updated the jFeed prototype to include the date field and the modified portion in jFeed that is parsing fine in everything other than firefox looks like this now:

c.date = jQuery(this).find("date").eq(0).text();

No errors are being thrown, and simply a null value is being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `:` in there with `\\` as it is a reserved character for jQuery.

See the docs on [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/),

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters (#;&,.+*~':"!^$=>|/@ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, if you have an an input with `name="names[]"`, you can use the selector `$("input[name=names\\[\\]]")`.

Try,

```
jQuery(this).find("dc\\:date")
```

Comment: Cool. I tried this before but it breaks it in chromium/chrome. After checking though, it fixes it for firefox. I guess my fix for now will be running both ways and returning whichever is actually picked up. thanks